# Calling an executable in VBA using command prompt with dynamic file path naming

Tags: python, vba, shell, executable

I currently have a macro that calls a python executable. However when I run the macro it doesnt seem to run. I know it's not a problem with the executable because when I double click on it it runs fine. I also don't think its a problem with the filepath.

What other possible problems could there be.

I've been working on this for the past 8 hours.

Relevant Code:

```
folderPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path

Dim stAppName As String

stAppName = folderPath & "\dist\MCM_MAT2.exe"
Call Shell(stAppName, 1)
```

Comment: Could you post the relevant code?

Comment: What do you have in the macro sub?

Comment: folderPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
    
    Dim stAppName As String


    stAppName = folderPath & "\dist\MCM_MAT2.exe"
    Call Shell(stAppName, 1)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your working directory needs to be set before you call the shell.

```
' Go to the desired startup directory. 
ChDir folderPath
```